# Create right arrow on div and arrow should appear on top of parent container on div hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a list of div items with a right arrow which I am able to do but the requirement is to show the arrow outside the parent, basically overlapping the div's parent. That's where I am stuck for a long time. I need this to do on a div's hover. Need quick help on this. Thanks.

HTML -

```
<div class="parentDiv">
   <div class="leftInnerDiv">
     <div class="list-container">
      <div>
       List Item 1
      </div>
      <div>
       List Item 2
      </div>
      <div>
       List Item 3
      </div>
      <div>
       List Item 4
      </div>
      <div>
       List Item 5
      </div>
      <div>
       List Item 6
      </div>
      <div>
       List Item 7
      </div>
      <div>
       List Item 8
      </div>
      <div>
       List Item 9
      </div>
      <div>
       List Item 10
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightInnerDiv">

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.parentDiv {
  background-color: #fff;
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
}
.leftInnerDiv {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  width: 40%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
.list-container {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 0, 25%));
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.list-container > div {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rd-color('background', 'surface');
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91.6% 0%, 100% 50%, 91.6% 100%, 0% 100%);
  width: 100%;
}
.list-container > div:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Current problem** -

[image]

**Expected output** -
[image]

**Here is a working fiddle to refer** - https://jsfiddle.net/ctvb5gam/1/

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin-right:-3px` (negative number required) to create an arrow outside the parent.

example:

html

```
<div class="parentDiv">
   <div class="leftInnerDiv">
     <div class="list-container">
      <div class="list-item">
         <div>
          List Item 1
          <span class="list-arrow"></span>
         </div>
      </div>
      ...
```

css

```
.list-container > .list-arrow{
  margin-right: -3px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for that? I tried this but didn't work for me. @Ardhi

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue.
Here is new css style.

```
.parentDiv {
  background-color: #fff;
  width:600px;
  height:400px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
}
.leftInnerDiv {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
  width: 40%;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* new */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px; /* new */
}
.list-container {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 0, 25%));
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-right: 10px; /* new */
}
.list-container > div {
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rd-color('background', 'surface');
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91.6% 0%, 100% 50%, 91.6% 100%, 0% 100%);
  /*width: 100%;*/
}
.list-container > div:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It didn't fix, it just added unnecessary padding but the arrow is not overlapping, you can check in the fiddle. It should cross the right border line ultimately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).